# GO: incorrect form value type passed as Fprintf argument

Tags: go

I'm trying to print a user's username that the user keyed into a form, using Fprintf:

GO code:

```
const logPage = `
<html>
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="Username" name="name"></input>
    ...
</form> 
</html>
`
const homePage = `
<html>
<h1>hi %s</h1>
</html>
`

func homehandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    a = r.FormValue("name")
    fmt.Fprintf(w, homePage, a) ---> how do I insert the a value in the required interface{} form?
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/home", homehandler)
    ...
}
```

According to this: http://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.FormValue, FormValue returns a string, but Fprintf seems to require an interface type: http://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Fprintf. How do I insert the correct value/type of "a" as in my code above? Or, is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Any type can satisfy the empty interface `interface{}`. The `fmt` package uses reflection to identify the underlying type. Have you tried using this?

Comment: the problem is that nothing gets printed out with my current code so I thought it could be because of "a"'s type

Comment: Judging from the code you posted, the `homeHandler` is invoked when viewing the `/home` page. The form supplying the name, submits to the `/login` page. Thus the submitted form data never reaches that handler.

Comment: `a` doesn't seems to be declared. And where is the page `/login` handled ?

Comment: Are you planning to use the _html/template_ library to inject values into your template?  You probably want to take a very serious look at it instead of what you'd doing now with Fprintf.  Doing the interpolation with traditional C-style interpolation is subject to XSS-style injection attacks.

Answer (score 0):

I am actually not sure if your code could work the way you intend it.

Here's a slightly modifiede, working example:

```
const logPage = `
<html>
<form action="/login" method="POST">
    <label for="name">Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="Username" name="name"></input>
    ...
</form> 
</html>
`
const homePage = `
<html>
<h1>hi %s</h1>
</html>
`


func loginhandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
  if r.Method == "GET" {
    fmt.Fprint(w, homePage)
  } else if r.Method == "POST" {
    // Here you can check the credentials
    // or print the page you wanted to
    // BUT please DON'T DO THIS
    a = r.FormValue("name")        
    fmt.Fprint(w, logpage, a)
    // DON'T DO THIS FOR THE SAKE OF YOUR USERS
  }
}

func main() {
    // http.HandleFunc("/home", homehandler) not needed
    http.HandleFunc("/login", loginhandler)
    ...
}
```

Here is how it goes:

1. The user makes a `GET` request to your `/login` page, and the `loginHandler` is called.
2. In your `loginhandler` you are returning the login page html to the user's browser.
3. Then the user enters it's data, and sends a `POST` request.
4. In the loginhandler the differentiation between the types of requests make it possible to either render the form, or display the values posted.

However, you should ALWAYS sanitize user data. The `template/html` does that for you, so please take a look. If you have other questions concerning the usage of that package, aks away!